# Adding inputs from a different model in a New form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have a many_to_many relation with **photos** and **sponsors**.

When creating a new Photo, in the new.html.erb view, I would like to add the **sponsor** attributes (which belong to a different model, but are relationed with photo), but I don't know how to.

I want to add **:sponsor_name, :sponsor_web** inputs in the Photo creation view, so I can add info about the sponsors the photo has when I create a new photo

I tried creating 2 simple_forms in the same view, one with the photo table attributes, and the other with the sponsor attributes, but didn't work.

**Mi view (new.html.erb)**

```
<%= simple_form_for [current_user, @photo] do |f| %>
                    <%= f.button :submit, "Subir Spot"%>
            <% end %>
```

**My Photos#new Controller**

```
def new
    @photo = Photo.new
    @sponsor = @photo.sponsors
end
```

Comment: Be careful, you are mixing singular and plural names for the same things. If you want to create or update multiple objects within one form, see `nested_attributes`.

Comment: Ok thank you, just looked at that. But, how about those nested attributes? Should I add them as well as strong parameters in Photos Controller? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Nested**

You'll want to use [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) in your `Photo` model:

```
#app/models/photo.rb
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :sponsors
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :sponsors
end
```

This gives you the ability to use a [`nested` form](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1):

```
#app/controllers/photos_controller.rb
class PhotosController < ApplicationController
   def new
       @photo = Photo.new
       @photo.sponsors.build
   end

   def create
       @photo = Photo.new photo_params
       @photo.save
   end

   private

   def photo_params
      params.require(:photo).permit(:photo, :params, sponsors_attributes: [:name, :web])
   end
end

#app/views/photos/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @photo do |f| %>
   # Photo attributes here
   <%= f.fields_for :sponsors do |s| %>
      <%= s.text_field :name %>
      <%= s.text_field :web %>
   <% end %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This will work to create a new `Sponsor` object when you make a new `Photo` object, thus providing you with the ability to pass *nested* data.

--

Although this will work for a `has_many :through` association, you'll want to be careful when using it with `has_and_belongs_to_many`, as if you just wanted to associate two models, you'll be better populating the `[other]_ids` method of your new `Photo` object

I can detail this if you want more information

Comment: Just worked out of the box. Understood perfectly. Thanks so much